# Hibernate 3.5 or 3.6 with no supporting to @Any annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I'm currently working on a system migration (from hibernate 3.2.2.GA with JPA1 to hibernate 3.6 with JPA2. The migration itself is very simple, there are no major updates to do (in fact, I don't think there is any at all).

The problem I'm facing is that hibernate throws an exception at runtime, complaining about the @Any annotations. The stacktrace is the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: any not supported yet
    at org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.AttributeFactory.determineAttributeMetadata(AttributeFactory.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.AttributeFactory.buildAttribute(AttributeFactory.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.MetadataContext.wrapUp(MetadataContext.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.buildMetamodel(MetamodelImpl.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:902)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:225)
```

So it means that @Any or @ManyToAny are no longer supported by hibernate. This is weird because the documentation (from 3.3 to 3.6) mentions how to use the @Any annotation and AFAIK there is no hibernate version that depreciates this annotation.

I checked hibernate 3.5 source code and the @Any annotation checking is there also, so it also throws the same exception.

Do you guys have any workaround for this issue?

thanks a lot!

Comment: They are not supported only if you use JPA interface. With `SessionFactory` they work fine.

Comment: that's strange...it works on hibernate 3.2 with jpa1. go figure. I'll stick with 3.2 for now =/

Comment: That's pretty clear. JPA2 includes metamodel support. Since it's not clear how to represent `@Any` attributes in a metamodel, they have to prohibit such attributes (it can be deduced from the stacktrace).

Comment: Do you know what would be the relative annotation to @Any in JPA2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would you please try to add this to your Hibernate properties:

```
hibernate.ejb.metamodel.generation=disabled
```

This should disable the metamodel generation, avoiding the exception you are seeing.
(Edited property value to say 'disabled' as pointed out in comments)

Comment: Thanks Partenon, I'll try that next week and report the outcome here.

Comment: A small amendment to your answer partenon: it's "disabled" instead of "disable". Other than that it truly works.  
Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you are not using hibernate.properties, add `<property name="hibernate.ejb.metamodel.generation" value="disabled" />` to your persistence.xml